# The order of a group with two generators

Tags: group-theory

> Let $G$ be an abelian group generated by $x$ and $y$ such that the order of $x$ is $16$, the order of $y$ is $24$ and $x^2=y^3$. What is the order of $G$?

The elements of $G$ are of the form $x^ny^m$ with $n=1,3,5,7,\cdots,15$ and $y=1,2,3,4,\cdots,23$. But I don't know how to quickly eliminate elements further, such as $xy^3=x\cdot x^2=x^3$. Can you help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: It is enough to take $n\in\{0,1\}$ and so the elements of $G$ are of the form $y^m$ or $xy^m$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the map ${\bf Z}/16{\bf Z}\times{\bf Z}/24{\bf Z}\to G$ extending $(1,0)\mapsto x$, $(0,1)\mapsto y$.

More specifically, invoke the first isomorphism theorem. What is the order of $(2,-3)$?

(Technically this yields that maximal possible order of $G$. Other possible orders are divisors of it.)

Comment: It should be pointed out that the statement in the brackets is true *in general*, but not here simply because any factor of the group $G$ constructed by anon will either not have an element of order $16$ or not have an element of order $24$. If we had $x^4=y^6$, say, as opposed to $x^2=y^3$ then the group $H$ constructed would not be unique as it maps onto $G$, and $G$ satisfies these conditions.